# Get last item linked via lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, lookup-column

Imagine I've got `List A` with a field `Name`

And `List B` with fields `Date` & `Name` (lookup from List A)

There are multiple items in `List B` linked to each item in `List A`.

I need to get the `Date` of the most recent item in `List B` linked to each item in `List A`.

Ideally I'd like to store it in a new field `Last Date` on `List A`.

Is this possible to do, for example, using SPD workflow?

(Both of the lists are exceeding the LVT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPD workflow can work for new created item in ListB easily:

Create SPD workflow in ListB, when a new item is created, the workflow will be triggered. It get the Name and Date value of the new item, and loop through all listA items to update Date value for the related item based on Name value.

For the existing items:

Firstly, you need to loop through all ListB items, set a workflow variable "ID", get each item ID, update the ID variable during looping. Then you can get most recent item > do the same operation above.

How to loop through list items via SPD workflow: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Glad to help you. You can accept my answer :)